# differentiabilty implies continuity (analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Is my proof correct? 
We need to show that if $f$ is differentiable at $x_o$, then it is continuous at $x_o$ i. e. 
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. }  |f(x)-f(x_o)|<\epsilon, \forall x\in X, |x-x_o|<\delta$$

Since f is differentiable then we have(Newton's approximation):
$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0 \text{ s.t. }  |f(x)-f(x_o)-L(x-x_o)|\leq \epsilon_1 |x-x_o|\leq \epsilon_1 |x-x_o|+\epsilon, \forall x\in X, |x-x_o|<\delta$$

Also we have:
$$|f(x)-f(x_o)|-|L||(x-x_o)|\leq|f(x)-f(x_o)-L(x-x_o)|\leq \epsilon_1 |x-x_o|+\epsilon$$
choose $\epsilon_1=-|L|$ 
then the inequality becomes:
$$|f(x)-f(x_o)| \leq \epsilon$$

Hence, the function is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beginning of the argument you have $|f(x) - f(x_0) - L(x - x_0)| \le \epsilon_1 |x - x_0|$ for small enough $\delta$. You can't later assert a value for $\epsilon_1$, and especially not a negative value.

Your argument can be repaired. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose $\delta_1$ so that $$|x - x_0| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - f(x_0) - L(x - x_0)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
If $L = 0$ the result followis immediately, so assume $|L| > 0$. It follows that 
$$|x - x_0| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| 
\le |L||x - x_0| + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
If, in addition, $|x - x_0| < \dfrac{\epsilon}{2 |L|}$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.  Thus
$$ |x - x_0| < \min\left\{ \delta_1,\frac{\epsilon}{2|L|} \right\} \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon.$$